# Deform2 multiselect with remote data source

Tags: html, pyramid, deform

I'm looking to have a form that has a field type multiselect using deform (as into this example http://deformdemo.repoze.org/select2_with_multiple/) but with choices coming from a remote data source (json call).

What will be the best way to implement it - is it possible with deform2 or should I just fall back to jquery etc.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely easier to populate the selection values on the server-side You can do this using colander *deferred* to set the `values` for the choice field:

```
@colander.deferred
def deferred_choices_widget(node, kw):
    choices = kw.get('choices')
    return deform.widget.SelectWidget(values=choices)


@colander.deferred
def deferred_default(node, kw):
    return kw['default']


class Schema(colander.Schema):
    pepper = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.String(),
        default=deferred_default,
        widget=deferred_choices_widget,
        )

def view(request):            

    # choices = (
    #    ('', '- Select -'),
    #    ('habanero', 'Habanero'),
    #    ('jalapeno', 'Jalapeno'),
    #    ('chipotle', 'Chipotle')
    #    )

    choices = load_data_from_some_api()

    schema = Schema().bind(choices=choices, default='jalapeno')
    form = deform.Form(schema, buttons=('submit',))

    return self.render_form(form)
```

However, to make it fast, you probably want to have some sort of cache. Usually a good pattern is

- Have a scheduled task (Celery) to fetch values from the API e.g. once in 60 minutes and store them in database
- Your view code doesn't perform any time expensive API calls, but always populates the values directly from the database

[Deform example](http://deformdemo.repoze.org/select_with_deferred/)

Comment: Hi Mikko, this is what I end up doing, FYI the data was sourced initial from a different api but found a way around it. thanks.